# parallel execution of mapreduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, job-control

I have a question. can I execute two or more jobs in hadoop concurrently with JobCntrol?
I have 2 jobs that can be execute in parallel and other jobs have dependencies with these two jobs? How can I do that with JobControl?
when I use it, it gives the error:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state RUNNING instead of DEFINE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a JobControl when you want to execute the jobs in parallel. Just submit the jobs using [JobClient.runJob()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html#runJob%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf%29) API. JobControl is used when there is a simple DAG of jobs.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply.. and another question.. I want to know what is chaining jobs for? I mean chainMapper and chainReducer.

Comment: @ Anse danesh : Inorder to know about chaining jobs , I have written a blog on it : http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/chaining-jobs-in-hadoop-mapreduce.html